# Trouble with curly braces in Entry URL Format / renderObjectTemplate

Tags: plugin-development, entries

This works:

```
{{ craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo(object).first.uri }}/{slug}
```

However, in this case, I need to use the extended `relatedTo` property, which includes curly braces:

```
{{ craft.entries({relatedTo: {targetElement: object, field: 'productConfigs'}}).first.uri }}/{{ object.slug }}
```

Because of the way `renderObjectTemplate` replacement [seems to happen](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles), the braces get screwed up.

Any way to work around this?

I'd actually rather do this in PHP/plugin if possible, but I'm not sure if a relevant hook/event exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not documented so I guess not officially supported, but you can use template variables in the URL formats. For example if you had a `UrlFormats` plugin, you could use something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class UrlFormatsVariable
{
    // Use in the URL Format box:
    // 
    //  {{ craft.urlFormats.yourSectionHandle(object) }}
    public function yourSectionHandle($entry)
    {
        // Craft checks the URL format with an array "object" first, to see if there's a {slug},
        // and so whether it should be checked for uniqueness and incremented if necessary.
        if (!$entry || !($entry instanceof EntryModel))
        {
            return '{slug}';
        }

        $relation = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)
            ->relatedTo(array(
                'targetElement' => $entry,
                'field'         => 'productConfigs',
            ))->first();

        if (!$relation)
        {
            // throw an exception or default to something
        }

        return $relation->uri.'/'.$entry->slug;
    }
}
```

Then you can keep your URL Format and Nested URL Format inputs cleaner:

```
{{ craft.urlFormats.yourSectionHandle(object) }}
```

Comment: returning '{slug}' didn't work for me. I would end up with an error message like "URI "{slug}" has already been taken."

Instead, this seems to do the trick: `{{ craft.urlFormats.yourSectionHandle(object)|default(object.slug) }}`

Comment: This is great - very handy if you want to get a little more complex with titles.  The twig mini templates are tricky/limited, but with this you can do basically anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using template variables in URL formats is brilliant, but if you don't want to write your own plugin, you could use the fantastic [Preparse](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) plugin as well.

First, create a Preparse field that contains the following Twig code, and add the field to your entry type's field layout:

```
{% spaceless %}
    {{ craft.entries({
        relatedTo: {
            targetElement: entry,
            field: 'productConfigs'
        }
    }).first().uri|default('') }}
{% endspaceless %}
```

Then, add the following to your URL format setting (`preparseFieldHandle` should be the handle for your Preparse field, obviously):

```
{{object.preparseFieldHandle ? object.preparseFieldHandle ~ '/'}}{slug}
```

Note that any existing entries in the relevant section would have to be re-saved in order to have the Preparse field actually parse.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the best answer, but since others can post answers too:

One solution to this may be to disable the Section setting *Entries in this section have their own URLs* and manage your URLs manually using a custom route and the appropriate template logic.

Comment: By disabling that setting you also disable live preview.

Comment: Good point. It would be possible to have URLs enabled for Live Preview and route things differently on the front-end. Not saying this is ideal. It always feels wrong when you have URLs enabled just for Live Preview or in a situation where the CP and front-end URLs need to be different.